# PDO bindParam changes my string

Tags: php, pdo

I've the following code to insert some data into my database:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `questions`(`title`,`content`,`set`,`date`) VALUES(:title,:content,:set,:date)";
    $stmt = $db -> prepare($query);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':content',$content,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':set',$set,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt -> bindParam('date',$date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> execute();
    echo '<script>alert("שאלה נוספה בהצלחה");</script>';
```

The problem is, whenever I view the inserted information in the DB, it turns to weird string such as: `&#1489;&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;&#1497;&#1514;`
I have no clue why it's happening!

P.S. If I insert English string, it's all right. It shows as a proper english in the DB. It happens when I insert data in my language.

Comment: Check the encoding on the table. You may need to change it to another encoding.

Comment: @aynber the encoding is UTF-8-GENERAL_CI, works PEREFECTLY with my language

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After inspecting it for a while, I found out what was the problem.

The form that I got the input from wasn't inside an HTML tags because it was a quick and very simple interface.

After giving that a thought, I tried to do the form inside  proper HTML tags. I've enclosed the `<form>` tag in this:

```
    <html dir="rtl">
    <head>
    <title>Insert a new question</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> // important line
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  </head>
 <body>
<!-- form here -->
</body>
</html
```

After doing that, the input given was a proper Hebrew letters instead of the HTML entity code.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for your attempt to help me, much appriciated. I tried what you suggested, but ended up with nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: As a matter of fact, your solution is a direct consequence of my answer. It was me who made you abandon that strange idea of bindParam spoiling your data and pointed you in the right direction. So, I am satisfied. Cheers :)

Comment: I guess you can say so. I was inspecting other things while waiting for an answer. So I tried doing other things and abandoned bindParam, so it's not like I wouldn't try anything else and stick to my first assessment. But hey, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @kfirba that was problem with encoding your page with HTML and you find solution. But it would be very nice if you accept your answer so your question will be removed from unanswered category. HaND :)

Answer (score -1):

It may be a problem with the character sets and collation. You may need them set to UTF-8

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: and how do I do that :o?

Comment: If you are using MySQL try:  ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;          Or if you need for tables
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Answer (score -1):

Remove the PDO::PARAM_STR from your bind and
use this in your code once :

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); //for utf unicodes
internal_encoding("your unicode"); //
```

OR

```
default_charset = "your unicode";
```

Comment: My unicode? what am I suppose to type there? BTW, my DB decleration is as following: `$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
`

Answer (score -2):

> whenever I view the inserted information in the DB, it turns to weird string such as: `&#1489;&#1506;&#1489;&#1512;&#1497;&#1514;` I have no clue why it's happening!

I have.
These symbols has **absolutely nothing to do with database.**
It's *HTML encoding* and mysql will never ever encode your data this way.

It's some other software that converts your data **before** adding it to DB. You can easily verify it just by outputting these characters (NOT rendered by browser, of course). Most likely its some sort of "all-sanitize" function which you definitely have to get rid of.

Comment: You can see my code above. Do you see any sanitize function? And yeah, if I'm echoing the string it's showing properly. Moreover, when I'm retrieving the data from the DB, it shows properly. But what if I want to store 40 chars max? It will convert it into hundreds and therefore won't store everything!

Comment: you have to see these characters **NOT rendered by browser, of course**. And please, don argue. Honestly, your case is quite silly and clear. bindParam don't change any strings ever.

Comment: I'm not arguing or anything. If bindParam doesn't change the string, what else can? There is no other function on the page. The lines before the code I posted are $title = $_POST['title']; and then directly bind it to the :title. What can cause it then? I really can't find anything wrong, it's just a basic code

Comment: First of all echo your title out in browser and then look at the **source code** of HTML page, not the rendered picture. and then start to trace these symbols back - up to the point where they appeared first.